# java watch processes that are using mic to record audio

Tags: java, javasound

please tell me is there any way to get the list of all processes that are currently using the mic to record audio ?

like Skype, sound recorder both are running. want to get them in java

Comment: Could you specify your platform?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can query all the input lines and ports via the class AudioSystem. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

I'm guessing you'll have to inspect the output of the various lines/ports in order to determine if they are active at a given moment.